# Generating metadata ("bindings" library) from C# DLL to Mono

Tags: c#, .net, binding, mono, wrapper

I have a C# library project targeting Windows 8.

I'd like to build a tool that will act similarly to what *tblimp* does:

1. Go over all public types in the library (DLL).
2. Export these into a new "wrapper" DLL (method bodies will be left blank, although this behaviour can be configured).

The new generated DLL could be referenced in other projects that didn't support the original DLL (just for the sake of building the project, since the methods themselves don't contain any functionality).

The main benefit is to use the generated DLL as a reference to Mono projects.

Is there any tool that allows doing this?

Comment: Is the original DLL a .NET-DLL or another type of DLL? And what kind of projects are the projects that cannot reference the original DLL's? Are they .NET-projects or other type of projects?

Comment: I'd like to take a Windows Store library DLL (C#) and wrap all its code so it can be referenced from Mono.

Answer (score 1):

I think that's possible if you can use Mono.Cecil to parse the original dlls (you might have to patch Cecil if in some corner cases it fails). Then with the objects you get in memory, you can generate whatever assemblies you need to disk and use the generated assemblies for your purposes.

There are many open source projects based on Cecil that can lead you in this path, such as Obfuscar (an open source obfuscator),

http://obfuscar.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing the same right now - I'm creating a tool called Piranha which removes all code and all non-public members leaving only a "skeleton".
It's not easy to make the resulting library CLS compliant.
There are problems with constructors: Constructors need to call base type constructors. But what if the constructor it calls is internal?
There are problems with structures: Looks like you cannot just remove all private fields since the size of the structure needs to be known (for a verifiable assembly).

But creating a skeleton library is not enough. You also need to remap/remove the references. Your Windows 8 library references WinRT libraries and won't be consumable by Mono libraries. You have to replace the WinRT library references with, most probably, PCL references form some profile. I still haven't done this part.

There also other referenced libraries. They'll drag their platform-specific references with them. So we need to either remove those references (and all members which depend on the types from those libraries) or convert the libraries to skeletons (and re-map the references).

If you're interested in such tool, I'll create a GitHub repo in few days and post the code there.

Comment: I am pretty sure we are both doing this for different reasons... What use do you have for such a tool /

Answer (score 0):

This tool already exists. It shipped with early versions of the .NET framework. It's called "SoapSuds."

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/323491